# powerpivot dates older than today

Tags: powerpivot

I am trying to create a calculated colum which basically states that if the [CloseDate] is blank and [LastModifiedDate] is older than 4 days return a numerical value.

I've started with =ISBLANK([CloseDate]) but can't seem to get the rest of the statmennt to work

I'm new to powerpivot so any help would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
MyColumn = 
IF(
    ISBLANK('table'[CloseDate]
        && TODAY() - 'table'[LastModifiedDate] > 4
    ,<your number to return>
    ,<else condition>
)
```